# Ошибка в коде по вычислению суммы чисел из строки

Tags: python

Смысл кода состоит в том, что вводится сумма чисел в виде строки (например, 15+3+27).
Вывести он должен сумму в виде числа (в данном случае 45).
Свой код прикрепила ниже (считает сумму неправильно).
Если не сложно, исправьте его, буду очень благодарна.

```
sum=str(input('Введите сумму трёх чисел(x+y+c):'))
N=0
b=str(0)
for x in sum: 
    if x!='+':
        b=b+x
    else:
        c=int(b)
        N=int(N+c)
print(N)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не обсуждая алгоритм и стиль, вот работающий код

```
s = input('Введите сумму трёх чисел(x+y+c):')
N = 0  # тут накапливаем сумму
b = 0  # тут собираем слагаемые
for x in s: 
    if x == '+':
        N += b    # число кончилось, можно складывать
        b = 0     # сбросим аккумулятор
    else:
        b = b*10+int(x)   # добавляем в число младший разряд
N += b  # прибавим последнее число      
print(N)
```

Comment: Спасибо за код!

Answer (score 1):

```
v = sum(int(i.strip()) for i in input('Введите сумму трёх чисел(x+y+c):').split('+'))
print(v)
```

Comment: я думаю. что автор циклы изучает :)

Comment: @splash58 я тоже думаю, что ваш ответ для неё лучше.

Answer (score -1):

Можно проще:

```
print(eval(input('Введите сумму трёх чисел(x+y+c):'))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]